# Extracting Child XML using ElementTree ignoring Namespace

Tags: python, xml, xml-parsing, elementtree

I have the following XML that I would like to extract a portion of the child if name matches "Adam"

```
<data>
    <a:config version="1.0" xmlns:a="uri:abc.com/a" xmlns:b="uri:abc.com/b">
  <a:xxx config="ABC">
      <set>option_on</set>
      <location>/123/123</location>
      <data>123</data>
  </a:xxx>
<a:xxx name="Adam">
  <a:yyy value="5555-5555">
    <log>true</log>
  </a:yyy>
</a:xxx>
  <a:xxx name="Lisa">
    <a:yyy value="2222-2222">
      <log>false</log>
    </a:yyy>
  </a:xxx>
</a:config>
</data>
```

I manage to extract the section but it doesn't output the original namespace rather it is showing ns0 and ns1. Below is my code

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
tree2 = ET.parse("mycode.xml")
root2= tree2.getroot()
for elem in tree2.iter(tag='{uri:abc.com/a}xxx'):
  match = elem.get('name')
  if match == "Adam":
    bla = ET.dump(elem)
```

Output as follows: -

```
<ns0:xxx xmlns:ns0="uri:abc.com/a" name="Adam">
    <ns0:yyy value="5555-5555">
      <log>true</log>
    </ns0:yyy>
  </ns0:xxx>
```

I am hoping to get exactly as what the original document is:-

```
<a:xxx name="Adam">
  <a:yyy value="5555-5555">
    <log>true</log>
  </a:yyy>
</a:xxx>
```

Comment: The XML document in the question is not well-formed. There are no declarations of the `a` and `b` namespace prefixes.

Comment: @mzjn you are right. I have corrected the sample data

Comment: I have done this with BeautifulSoup but the server I am working with didn't have bs4 installed. Hopefully someone has a solution to this using ElementTree. Thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the [`register_namespace`](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/xml.etree.elementtree.html#xml.etree.ElementTree.register_namespace) function.

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET

tree2 = ET.parse("mycode.xml")
root2 = tree2.getroot()

# Register the 'a' prefix to be used when serializing
ET.register_namespace("a", "uri:abc.com/a")

for elem in tree2.iter(tag='{uri:abc.com/a}xxx'):
    match = elem.get('name')
    if match == "Adam":
        bla = ET.dump(elem)
```

Output:

```
<a:xxx xmlns:a="uri:abc.com/a" name="Adam">
  <a:yyy value="5555-5555">
    <log>true</log>
  </a:yyy>
</a:xxx>
```

This is not the exact output that you asked for. You cannot force ElementTree to omit the namespace declaration (because doing so would make the output ill-formed).