# Python updated xml file different form the original file

Tags: python, xml, elementtree

So, I have an xml file and created a script in python to change some values, which works just fine but when I create the output.xml (xml with updated values), the schema changes. I want to keep the same schema and update the values.

my script.py

```py
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET

tree = ET.parse('file_to_be_updated.xml')
root = tree.getroot()

for entry in root.iter('tratamento'):
    current_text = entry.text.rstrip()
    entry.text = current_text + '_new'

tree.write('output.xml')
```

What I get:

[Comparison between the two files](https://i.stack.imgur.com/v6uON.png)

In this output file we missed the first line `<?xml version = "1.0" encoding="Windows-1252" standalone="yes"?>` and the `xsd` become `xs` in the schema.

Is there a way to generate an updated xml but keep everything else the same?

Comment: If I'm not mistaken, ElementTree only handles the parsing, you need to specify the encoding do you want to read/write.

Comment: Regarding the XML declaration, see https://stackoverflow.com/q/15356641/407651. Regarding the namespace prefix, see https://stackoverflow.com/q/49257216/407651. These are just examples, there are several other similar questions.

Comment: The write() from xml.etree.ElementTree doesn’t support a xml_declaration with [standalone](https://bugs.python.org/issue45336).

Comment: For `standalone`, see https://stackoverflow.com/q/68023690/407651 for a workaround.